# Fullstory SDK iOS not capturing screens on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, fullstory

Fullstory sdk - https://help.fullstory.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042772333-Getting-Started-with-iOS-Data-Capture is not capturing screen on simulator. Getting following message in logs:

```
[FullStory] Info: got UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification but capture is inactive; not starting session
```

I am using Mac OS M2 13.6 version and 1.42.0 version of Fullstory iOS SPM. I have tried it using

1. Xcode 15 - Simulator 17.0(Rosetta), 16.2(Rosetta), 15.0(Rosetta)
2. Xcode  14.3.1 - - Simulator 16.2(Rosetta), 15.0(Rosetta)

How do I enable capturing screens on simulator?

Answer (score 1):

There should be more output that indicates why capture didn't start. My guess is either the org has capture disabled or doesn't have the Mobile add-on. You should see some log output that indicates a "[reason code](https://help.fullstory.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020829553-Why-is-data-capture-blocked-on-my-site-)". That will tell you why capture didn't start. The article talks about reading network requests to /rec/page, but the same reason code will show up in run-time logs while trying to capture a session. Capture works on physical devices as well as simulators. If you still need help, shoot us a message at mobile-support@fullstory.com.

Source: I'm a Support Engineer @ FullStory.